# Rails Routing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a website in people can browse artists and their albums. I have setup my routes like so:

```
match 'albums/[:id]/[:album_id]' => 'albums#show', :as => 'artist_album'
```

I tried setting up a nested route like:

```
resources :artists do
resources :albums
end
```

but I can't figure out how to achieve the routing like in the first example... but thats a different question... This is my code when trying to render `artist_album_path`

```
<%= link_to image_tag("#{album["Images"]["Album150x150"]}", width: "122", alt: "#{@term}", class: "float-left"), artist_album_path("/#{CGI::escape(album["Artist"]["Name"])}/#{CGI::escape(album["Title"])}") %>
```

I keep getting this error:
`No route matches {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"show", :id=>"/Beastie+Boys/Licensed+To+Ill"}`

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In routes.rb:

```
match 'albums/:id/:album_id' => 'albums#show', :as => 'artist_album'
```

In your view:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(...), artist_album_path(:id => ..., :album_id => ...) %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your answer, but I am getting this error now: `No route matches {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"show", :id=>"Beastie+Boys", :album_id=>"Don%27t+Play+No+Game+That+I+Can%27t+Win+%28Feat.+Santigold%29+%28Remix+EP%29"}`

Comment: Nevermind, I changed the `album_id` to be the exact ID of the album vs the album title... it was causing issues for some reason

Comment: You can use `friendly_id` gem for artist names/album titles in routes.

Comment: The only issue with the friendly_id gem is that the titles of items are coming from an API call out vs a DB call